# BBcode to HTML parser

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a good parser, and so far, nothing seems good enough to replicate what the typical php forum can do.

I have tried [bbcodeParser](https://github.com/wGEric/phpBB-BBCode-Javascript-Parser) and [XBBCodeParser](https://github.com/patorjk/Extendible-BBCode-Parser/).

I am looking for at least the following functions:

`[b]`, `[i]`, `[quote]`, `[quote='user name']` `[img]`, `[url]`, `[list]`, `[video]` etc.

What I am looking for, is a parser that is like [SCEditor](http://www.sceditor.com/), except instead of typing, the user is supposed to see the content with BB code.

Thanks.